# PDO Exception : Could not find driver.

Tags: sql-server-2008, laravel, ubuntu, pdo, lamp

[PDOException] could not find driver when trying to connect remote MSSQL databse on local machine on lamp in laravel project

Comment: Create database first then run migration

Comment: If you're running sqlsrv as the database driver then you have to install the drivers. It only works in a 32bit version of php